# Html fileuploader not working with ios7 in phonegap application page becomes black when upload image

Tags: cordova

Html fileuploader not working with ios7 in phonegap application  page becomes black when upload image.Its working with ipad and ios 5 properly

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this file transfer phonegap plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: It is not working make sure only filetransfer.js is include or any other included with this

Comment: make sure you build your cordova project after add this plugin.

Comment: after add this plugin its give error for require is not defined which used in given plugin

Comment: var argscheck = require('cordova/argscheck'),

Comment: can you send me your cordova project though dropbox link?

Comment: can you post your related source code in your question?

Comment: jst i use cardova.js nd jquerymobile/1.3 min. js and use html file uploader in my code after upload an image its save by web handler

Comment: its all process working in ipad nd ios5 bt not work with ios7